# Yii UrlManager route to own controller instead of module

Tags: php, yii

I have just gotten started with the Yii framework, trying to create a simple application. I have added the yii-user-management module (YUM) and have followed the short [installation tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/195/implementing-a-registration-process-using-the-yii-user-management-module/).

Following the tutorial, I created a RegistrationController that extends the YumRegistrationController - then tried loading it in the browser. However, regardless of how I change the config for UrlManager, I cannot get my own controller or view loaded (the view was copied to protected/views/registration.registration.php as instructed).

I am not the only one with the same problem - see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7591-module-yii-user-management-module/page__st__320) for example - but I cannot get any of the solutions working. Not even renaming the controller has worked, so I figure that there is something fundamentally wrong with my UrlManager settings.

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>false,   
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

The YumRegistrationController gets loaded every time, or I get a 404 error.

I have tried additional rules, like:

```
'registration' => 'application.controllers.Registration',
```

or (after renaming)

```
'registration' => '//MyRegistration/registration',
```

and even

```
'registration' => '//registration/registration/registration',
```

like in an article I read, but nothing worked.

Please help - I would really love to move on to creating an app instead of just working on the setup...

**UPDATE**: /registration/registration/registration works, it just shows the default view and loads the controller for YUM registration...

**Yii version 1.1.10**

Comment: why double forward slashes? does 'registration' => 'registration/registration/registration' or 'registration' => 'registration/registration' work?

Comment: double slashes are from http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7591-module-yii-user-management-module/page__st__320  - removing them produces the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think , you have user component registered in your config  main.php. So please share that. I can help.

.     'loginUrl' => array('/user/user/login'),  may cause problem. no need to change urlManager.

```
         'user'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.components.WebUser',
          'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
          'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),
          ),
```

Comment: I actually had to drop this project due to the difficulty of getting things up and running. But I'll accept the answer...

Comment: Thank. I wish I could help earlier.